# customScript.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="customScript.js"></script>
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="docs/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/facebookicn.png">

    <title>Facbook</title>


    <link href="dist/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
```

//this is in coustom.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

//this is in html

```
    <div class="col-md-6 txtfeild ">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!"><input id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"  type="text" onblur="validateName()" ></a>
       </div>
```

i am getting error like this 
customScript.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at customScript.js:1 tried many methods but cannot resolve this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `customScript` fires before you are importing the `jQuery` script. Move the import line above the `customScript` import.

```
<script src="docs/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="customScript.js"></script>
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is loaded after you load customScript.js so the variable $ is undefined.
You have to insert the script after you load jQuery.

```
<head>
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="docs/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="customScript.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/facebookicn.png">

    <title>Facbook</title>


    <link href="dist/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to use Jquery in your script you first need to load it

```
<script


src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

add this line before your `customeScript` to add jquery through cdn or set the path to the jquery files if you have downloaded it